# Efeito :focus sobrepondo :active

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

É possível visualiza o efeito de `:active` mesmo tendo `:focus?` estou tentando aqui mas quando clico no elemento o efeito de `:active` não é mostrado pulando direto para `:focus`.

```css
.btn{
  color: black;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-color: #CCC;
  outline: none;
}
.btn:active{
  color: #333;
  background-color: red;
}
.btn:focus{
  color: #333;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">button</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Altere a ordem no CSS. Coloque `:focus` antes do `:active`.

```
.btn:focus{
  color: #333;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
}
.btn:active{
  color: #333;
  background-color: red;
}
```

**Por que antes?**

O CSS funciona de cima pra baixo. Quando você declara um estilo antes para um elemento e outro depois, o que vem depois irá *sobrescrever* o que foi declarado antes. Quando você clica no botão, ele terá as duas *pseudo-classes*: `:active` e `:focus`, logo, o que vier depois terá prioridade no efeito sobre o elemento. Alterando a ordem, enquanto você está clicando no botão, ele terá o efeito do `:active` acima do `:focus`, e quando soltar o clique, ele estará apenas com `:focus`. Quando você clicar fora do botão, ele perderá o `:focus` e voltará ao estado normal.

**Veja:**

```css
.btn{
  color: black;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-color: #CCC;
  outline: none;
}
.btn:focus{
  color: #333;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
}
.btn:active{
  color: #333;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">button</button>
```

Comment: perfeito, muito obrigado